# Why do we talk about $U(1)$-principal bundles rather than torus bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I'm trying to understand gauge theory in terms of differential geometry, and one thing I'm confused about is why we talk about $U(1)$-principal bundles when the gauge potential $A$ usually has multiple components on manifolds with dimension $d\ge 2$? Shouldn't we talk about torus $U(1)\times\cdots\times U(1)$ bundles instead?

I guess one reason/example that I can think of is we usually want to compute gauge invariant variables, such as the Wilson loop or Berry phase, where we compute the phase change (or holonomy) along a particular closed loop. A pullback onto the loop would then probably correspond to a $U(1)$-bundle. However, in general, it would seem that we would like to talk about torus bundles.

Comment: In $U(1)$-gauge theory there is only 1 factor of $U(1)$. The multiple components are only space(time)-components.